# JS MediaTags year info not present

Tags: javascript, audio, id3

I am using [JS MediaTags](https://github.com/aadsm/jsmediatags) *latest* version but I cannot get the year information to show up.  I do have year info visible when I check my songs in the [Mp3tag](https://www.mp3tag.de) editor.

If I look into the JS MediaTags source code I can see `TYE` is used for this. I don't get `TYE` but only the following:

> [image: JSON-like metadata recognized by JS MediaTags]
>
> ```json
> Object {
>   APIC: {
>     id: 'APIC',
>     size: 34574,
>     description: 'Attached picture',
>     data: {…}
>   }
>   TALB: {
>     id: 'TALB',
>     size: 39,
>     description: 'Album/Movie/Show title',
>     data: 'Notte di Natale - Giovedì 24 12 1991'
>   }
>   TCON: {
>     id: 'TCON',
>     size: 17,
>     description: 'Content type',
>     data: 'Tempo di Natale'
>   }
>   TIT2: {
>     id: 'TIT2',
>     size: 69,
>     description: 'Title/songname/content description',
>     data: 'Notte di Natale Il cristianesimo e credere veramente che Dio ci ama'
>   }
>   TPE1: {
>     id: 'TPE1',
>     size: 15, 
>     description: 'Lead performer(s)/Soloist(s)', 
>     data: 'Divo Barsotti'
>   }
>   TXXX: {
>     id: 'TXXX',
>     size: 11,
>     description: 'User defined text information frame',
>     data: {…}
>   }
>   album: "Notte di Natale - Giovedì 24 12 1991"
>   artist: "Divo Barsotti"
>   genre: "Tempo di Natale"
>   picture: {
>     format: 'image/jpeg', 
>     type: 'Cover (front)', 
>     description: '', 
>     data: Array(34560)
>   }
>   title: "Notte di Natale Il cristianesimo e credere veramente che Dio ci ama"
>   [[Prototype]]: Object
> ```

Comment: No, it is either IDv2.3 or IDv2.4 `TYER` (since you also have 4 letter frames already) instead of `TYE` (ID3v2.2), or you also have an ID3v1 tag where it may come from. Adding an excerpt of the first 512 (and last 128) bytes of your file would help. Have you contacted the vendor/[filed an issue](https://github.com/aadsm/jsmediatags/issues) instead of asking here? Please post text instead of pictures - nobody is able to select portions of text out of a picture.

Comment: After 12+ years you should be aware of formatting your Qs better and use correct names of products (and linking to them, eliminating ambiguity). Also your Q neither contains one actual question, nor the file's payload bytes as requested (use a [hex editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor).